# WIll my phone provider update me to Windows 10 Mobile if I use Technical Preview?

Tags: insider-preview, windows-10-mobile

I'm concerned that I will always be stuck with the technical preview once installing Windows 10 Mobile on my 8.1 device. I am a member of the technical preview as of February when the build was impossible to use. Now that 10 will be launching in Oct. or Nov. I'd like to go ahead and dive in. I do not want to mess up my device.

Answer (score 1):

You're phone provider will no longer be providing the updates to your phone.  Instead, they will come direct from Microsoft.  Once using the insider program you can opt out at any time.  In other words, your phone will update to the same version as is publicly released.  If you want to stay there, simply disable the insider preview.

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be okay with that condition. As long as i use Windows 10 Tech Preview on my PC, it will get an upgrade to the stable version.

or in the nutshell, you could downgrade it for a while just for waiting the stable update from Ms (Windows 10 Mobile RTM)

Comment: I would have probably reverted back to 8.1 using the Windows Phone Recovery Tool, then updated via the manufacturers update, but the WIndows 10 Mobile Technical Preview bricked my phone so bad not even the button combinations will boot it..